# "No alive nodes found in your cluster" error in magento 2.1.6 after elasticsearch

Tags: magento2, save, magento2.1.6, elasticsearch

Every time I save a new product I get that error

> "No alive nodes found in your cluster"

My version of **magento is 2.1.6** and the problem appeared after installing the elasticsearch module

[image]

What could be a solution to this problem? this also does not let me delete products or change their data

Comment: Related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/318664/1883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you should check.

1. Check the elastic search hostname and the port are correct and accessible.

   telnet elastic-search-host port
2. Run full reindex, which will create elastic search nodes during indexing.

Comment: @B G Kavinga where to check  elastic search hostname and the port?

Comment: You can find it under Stores=>Configuration=>Catalog=>Catalog Search

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Check if ElasticSearch is working and accessible from Magento server

In order to test your connection, log in to your SSH and type

`curl http://localhost:9200`

If you get a JSon as response, your elasticsearch is working. Just replace the address and port above as your needs.

### 2. Check if the setting is correct in Magento

The settings are usually stored in the `core_config_data` table. A `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path like '%elastic%'` would be enough to retrieve the data.

It seems obvious, but we have a catch here:

In previous versions of Magento, those values were saved under the prefix `catalog/search/elasticsearch*`, but **in newer versions the path got a `7` in the end**.

Now, the hostname for example, is now saved as `catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname`.

In my case, I spent almost an hour to realize that after restoring an old db dump. I hope now you don't.

And of course, you can also change those values with `bin/magento config:set`, as follows:

- `bin/magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname ELASTIC-HOSTNAME` default is `localhost`
- `bin/magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_port ELASTIC-PORT` default is `9200`

and so on as described [here](https://www.magenteiro.com/blog/magento-2/configurando-elasticsearch/#elasticsearch-bin-magento).

Answer (score 1):

This error also appears when your elastic search server is not running, you can try if above solution is not working for you.

```
 sudo -i service elasticsearch start
```

You can check the status of elasticsearch node status by this command

```
 curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/health?v&pretty'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Elasticsearch is not installed or active. Before you reindex you can check Elasticsearch configuration from Backend. In admin panel you can test the elastic search connection. Please make sure the host and server port are matched with your configuration. Goto Admin -> Store -> configuration -> catalog -> catalog

[image]

After this, clear cache and reindex. It will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Elasticsearch is not installed or active. Before you reindex you can check Elasticsearch configuration from Backend. In admin panel you can test the elastic search connection. Please make sure the host and server port are matched with your configuration. Goto Admin -> Store -> configuration -> catalog -> catalog

[image]
After this, clear cache and reindex. It will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 'catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname' is set with proper hostname in core_config_data of db table.

For local magento I have set the value to 'localhost'. Please check screenshot for more clarification - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lynIX.png