# Magento 2.4.0 ElasticSearch not alive

Tags: magento-upgrade, elasticsearch, setup-upgrade, magento2.4

When performing the `setup:upgrade` I get this error :

```
"Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster"
```

I have not enabled It previously, updating from `Magento 2.3.5 p1`.

Comment: Please make sure, you are using default magento MySQL search. Admin login >> Store >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Catalog search >> Engin it should be Mysql >> Save.

Comment: MySql search is removed from M2.4, set Elasticsearch engine from Store >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Catalog search >> Engin

Comment: Thanks, your response was cut off.  What value do I set this to if I dont want elastic search.

Answer (score 4):

You must enable ElasticSearch in Magento 2.4, it's a requirement as you can see in the page [Magento 2.4 technology stack requirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html).

> You should use ElastiSearch 7, not ElasticSearch 6 as Magento 2.3

First, check if your ElasticSearch in installed and running, you can do via admin panel in the page **Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search**, and click in the test button.

[image: Magento 2.4 ElasticSearch 7]

Or using this command below, if required you can change the localhost and port.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search' -d '{
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "testField" : "abc"
    }
  }
}'
```

Via terminal, you can check which search engine you're using today and set it to ElasticSearch 7.

```
bin/magento config:show catalog/search/engine
bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine elasticsearch7
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess I have just found my anser, according to the following:

"MySQL is no longer used for search. You must use Elasticsearch.

You must install and configure Elasticsearch 7.6.x before upgrading to Magento 2.4.0. New installations require a connection to Elasticsearch to complete."

So I will need to stop and get familiar with elastic search, did I mention I couldnt log in to admin because of 2fa was enabled?
And by the way had to learn the command line for installing.

With M1 going away and M2 replacing, it seems there are still major changes that effect the backward compatibility of the product.  Im glad I only have M1 production product right now, but trying to get to M2.  Seems every release provides new surprises with changes to functionality , prerequisites that takes me days to install and get working.

love it

Answer (score 0):

Seem that your elasticsearch hostname is invalid. Try to find this path:

```
catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname
```

on you `core_config_data` table and correct it with your host name. For example, if you install your project on local host, set value to:

```
localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Magento 2.4.x** then you should be using **ElasticSearch 7**.

Check `app/etc/env.php` for ElasticSearch settings.

Example:

```
'system' => [
        'default' => [
            'catalog' => [
                'search' => [
                    'engine' => 'elasticsearch6',
                    'elasticsearch6_server_hostname' => 'opensearch',
                    'elasticsearch6_server_port' => '9200',
                    'elasticsearch6_index_prefix' => 'magento'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

If you see `elasticsearch6`, then change those to `elasticsearch7`.

Like this:

```
'system' => [
        'default' => [
            'catalog' => [
                'search' => [
                    'engine' => 'elasticsearch7',
                    'elasticsearch7_server_hostname' => 'opensearch',
                    'elasticsearch7_server_port' => '9200',
                    'elasticsearch7_index_prefix' => 'magento'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

Run config import:

```
bin/magento app:config:import
```

Refresh Cache:

```
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now, `bin/magento setup:upgrade` should run fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento#setup make sure to not put localhost:9200 in the servers list as this is visbile to your host machine but if you do [image]
so the correct settings are [image]

Answer (score -1):

Run `bin/magento config:show catalog/search/engine` if you then get the value `mysql` change it to Elasticsearch by running `bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine elasticsearch7`.

Than you can run the `setup:upgrade` command again.

Comment: I did run config:show, it came back with no entry.  Im upgrading from a 2.3.5 database.  Entered command to change to elasticsearch7 and it added.  Apparently 2.4 defaults to elastic search because when I run the setup it states the same error.  I dont have an elastic server setup.  What value goes into this configuration.  I did try mysql and of course got the message its not supported.  Ive not had experience with elasticsearch, but assume it takes an external server.  I dont want to set that up.

Comment: Well in that case the error appear because you do not have Elasticsearch running on your server. Sinds 2.4 Magento no longer support mysql as search engine and it is required to use Elastic. So to upgrade from 2.3.5 you need to install Elasticsearch 7+ to your server.